# Powershell to replace null value in csv cell with adjacent value

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to replace null values in the Team2 column in a csv file with the adjacent value in the Team1 column using PowerShell. I'm completely new so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I have the CSV in this format and several values in the Team2 column will be null values:

```
test   test2    Team1    Team2
----   -----    -----    ----- 
0000   aaaaa    Name1    Name6
0001   wwwww    Name2   
0004   ttttt    Name3    Name8
0005   ttttt    Name4 
0006   hhhhh    Name5    Name10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for asking specific programming questions. In order for us to help you, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us the code you've written to attempt to solve your problem and describe how the behavior of your code differs from the expected behavior. Following these steps increases the likelihood of someone answering your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use the `Import-CSV` cmdlet to import your file to an object. Then you can loop through your object to look for places where `Team2` is null or empty. There is a string method that checks just that and returns `$True` or `$False`. So this can be the conditional in an `If` Block. Then we'll return the value so that it can be passed down the pipeline to the `Export-CSV`

```
Import-CSV $FilePath | ForEach-Object {
    If  ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Team2)) {
        $_.Team2 = $_.Team1
    }
    $_
} | Export-CSV $ExportPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method

```
ipcsv $FilePath | %{if(!$_.Team2) {$_.Team2 = $_.Team1} ; $_ } |  epcsv $ExportPath -notype
```